# Глобальная перегрузка cout

Tags: c++

Можно ли как-то глобально перегрузить `cout <<`? Причем сама перегрузка должна зависить от содержимого параметров коммандной строки. Что порекомендуете?

```
void TestFun(){
    cout << "anything" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        if (argv[1] == "-indentFormat") {
               // тут одна перегрузка
        }
        else { // тут другая }
    }
    // далее все вызовы cout << приводят к перегруженной версии
    // причем желательно даже из других функций
    TestFun(); // cout внутри будет работать с перегруженным '<<'
}
```

Comment: А вам зачем? Вызывайте функцию, принимающую std::ostream&, в которую по необходимости передавайте то, что необходимо (std::cout или ваш кастомный наследний std::ostream).

Comment: @free_ze пример в студию, слабо понимаю)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/t89sjSfk

Comment: @free_ze необходимо чтобы в зависимости от параметров коммандной строки cout выводил все значения с отступом. Я думал создать свой класс и в нем поле (флаг отступа) и метод вывода. Перед проверкой создать обьект класса, в зависимости от параметра выставить флаг отступа. Далее использовать функцию вывода через экземпляр класса, ну и функциям другим тоже передавать его. Но такое решение кажется весьма тяжелым и не элегантным.

Comment: Сделайте проксирующую обертку, в которую (через конструктор) передадите ostream (в виде cout), а в переопределенном operator<< будете выполнять необходимые манипуляции над выводом с cout.

Comment: @free_ze можно подробней или лучше псевдокод или код)... сейчас сделал так (ниже ссылка). я так понял у вас схожее решение ? мое меня не устраивает тем, что глобализация никакая. всем функциям надо будет передать мой обьект. + проблема с обработкой двух вызовов "<<"

Comment: https://pastebin.com/AE6gfZFD

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59382/discussion-between-evgen8-and-free-ze).

Comment: а может вам банально хватит `freopen(stdout,"log.txt","w")`

Comment: Вы хотите mock'нуть синглтон. Неудивительно, что это сложно. (Это, кстати, одна из причин, по которой синглтоны не любят.)